# Data truncated when strncpy() used for copying string in MFC

Tags: c++, string, mfc, buffer-overflow, strncpy

In order to fix a buffer overflow Coverity issue, I have used **strncpy()** to copy a list item. The list item needs to be drag and dropped from one row to another. So the string that needs to be copied contains '\n', '\t' and ' ' characters.

I have used the below code.

```
for (int nColumn = 1; nColumn < nColumns; nColumn++)
{
    strncpy(lvItem.pszText, (LPCTSTR)(GetItemText(nDragIndex, nColumn)), sizeof(lvItem.pszText)-1);
    lvItem.pszText[sizeof(lvItem.pszText)] = '\0';
    lvItem.iSubItem = nColumn;
    SetItem(&lvItem);
}
```

The Coverity scan passed but the data in some of the columns gets truncated. I have heard of using **strcpy_s** method but is not available. Can anyone help me resolve issue?

Comment: Remove the line lvItem.pszText[sizeof(lvItem.pszText)] = '\0'; entirely. The string is already null-terminated

Comment: @peakpeak -- the **source** string is nul-terminated. Adding the `'\0'` is an attempt to work around using the wrong tool. `strncpy` does not add a nul terminator if it hits the end of the target range. It was never intended to be a "safe" alternative to `strcpy`.

Comment: `(LPCTSTR)` is likely part of your problem. I mean when you have to cast string pointers you are likely casting from the wrong type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong and doesn't do what you expect. `lvItem.pszText` is a pointer and it has a fixed size of 4 respective 8 bytes depending on the kind of your project. So your sizeof operator causes the truncation.

Using `LVITEM` in this way, need a buffer that this defined by you!

If you use `GetIemText`, you can also user [CListCtrl::SetItemText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hfshke78.aspx#clistctrl__setitemtext) This function takes care about all limits.